# Finding the nearest matching timestamp and writing coordinates to it (R)

Tags: r, csv, gps, timestamp

I'm performing some biological research which involves recording short time stamped digital audio files onto a device, in conjunction with a time synced GPS device. The track function of the GPS automatically records a time stamped xy point every 20 seconds, I'm then manually matching the time stamped audio files to the nearest track point for later analysis in GIS software. This process is time consuming and has a considerable margin for human error, so I'm keen to work out a way in R with which to automate this process.

So I have 2 .csv files;

one with the audio files ("calls") and times in hh:mm:ss:

```
FileName  Time
M00002    22:09:29
M00015    22:12:36
M00016    22:12:41
M00017    22:12:57
M00019    22:13:18
M00032    22:18:55
M00035    22:19:13
```

and so on

And a "track" file with 20 second time intervals in hh:mm:ss and X and Y columns with coordinates:

```
track_seg_point_id real.time         X        Y
1                    0  22:08:52 -1.886330 53.87816
2                    1  22:09:12 -1.886261 53.87811
3                    2  22:09:32 -1.886175 53.87808
4                    3  22:09:52 -1.886071 53.87806
5                    4  22:10:12 -1.885923 53.87805
6                    5  22:10:32 -1.885799 53.87803
7                    6  22:10:52 -1.885659 53.87800
8                    7  22:11:12 -1.885513 53.87797
9                    8  22:11:32 -1.885414 53.87795
10                   9  22:11:52 -1.885334 53.87793
```

I'm looking for a way to match the time stamped audio file with the nearest 20 second track point, then write the coordinates into the .csv file. Is this possible within R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**

```
gps <- read.table(header = TRUE,
                  text = "track_seg_point_id real.time         X        Y
1                    0  22:08:52 -1.886330 53.87816
2                    1  22:09:12 -1.886261 53.87811
3                    2  22:09:32 -1.886175 53.87808
4                    3  22:09:52 -1.886071 53.87806
5                    4  22:10:12 -1.885923 53.87805
6                    5  22:10:32 -1.885799 53.87803
7                    6  22:10:52 -1.885659 53.87800
8                    7  22:11:12 -1.885513 53.87797
9                    8  22:11:32 -1.885414 53.87795
10                   9  22:11:52 -1.885334 53.87793")

gps$real.time <- strptime(gps$real.time, "%H:%M:%S")
lo <- read.table(header = TRUE,
                 text = "FileName  Time
M00002    22:09:29
M00015    22:12:36
M00016    22:12:41
M00017    22:12:57
M00019    22:13:18
M00032    22:18:55
M00035    22:19:13")

lo$Time <- strptime(lo$Time, "%H:%M:%S")
```

**Code**

```
timeDiffs <- outer(lo$Time, gps$real.time, FUN = `-`)
ret <- cbind(lo, gps[apply(timeDiffs, 1, function(.) which.min(abs(.))), ])
```

**Explanation**

First, calculate the difference between all time stamps in the audio csv and the ones in the track csv by `outer`. You get a matrix with differences in seconds between the audio time stamp and each time stamp in the `gps` data.

```
timeDiffs[1:3,]
# Time differences in secs
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   37   17   -3  -23  -43  -63  -83 -103 -123  -143
# [2,]  224  204  184  164  144  124  104   84   64    44
# [3,]  229  209  189  169  149  129  109   89   69    49
```

Now, we apply over the rows of this matrix to get the minimum of the absolute values. The index of the minimum is the row in data frame `gps` which is the closest to the respective time stamp in the audio. Finally, we `cbind` the two files together:

```
#      FileName                Time track_seg_point_id           real.time
# 3      M00002 2015-07-13 22:09:29                  2 2015-07-13 22:09:32
# 10     M00015 2015-07-13 22:12:36                  9 2015-07-13 22:11:52
# 10.1   M00016 2015-07-13 22:12:41                  9 2015-07-13 22:11:52
# 10.2   M00017 2015-07-13 22:12:57                  9 2015-07-13 22:11:52
# 10.3   M00019 2015-07-13 22:13:18                  9 2015-07-13 22:11:52
# 10.4   M00032 2015-07-13 22:18:55                  9 2015-07-13 22:11:52
# 10.5   M00035 2015-07-13 22:19:13                  9 2015-07-13 22:11:52
#              X        Y
# 3    -1.886175 53.87808
# 10   -1.885334 53.87793
# 10.1 -1.885334 53.87793
# 10.2 -1.885334 53.87793
# 10.3 -1.885334 53.87793
# 10.4 -1.885334 53.87793
# 10.5 -1.885334 53.87793
```

Now, you can use `write.csv` to write the `data.frame` back to a file.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Adapted it to work with
    read.csv
to take in the entire dataset